# Positive solutions with fsolve in Maple

Tags: math, solver, maple

In Maple I use

```
solve(abs(-5.58 * L^(-1.88)) = 3, L);
```

and I get the results

```
L = 1.39 or L = -1.39
```

but if I use

```
fsolve(abs(-5.58 * L^(-1.88)) = 3, L);
```

I only get the result

```
L = -1.39
```

How can I make sure I get the positive result using `fsolve`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid the **avoid** option. You can specify a range in which you want the solutions to fall, like this:

```
fsolve(abs(-5.58 * L^(-1.88)) = 3, L= 0..infinity);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=fsolve : "For a general equation or system of equations, the fsolve command computes a single real root. "

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=fsolve%2fdetails : "Using the avoid option to find additional solutions"

```
S1:=fsolve(abs(-5.58 * L^(-1.88)) = 3, L );
S2:=fsolve(abs(-5.58 * L^(-1.88)) = 3, L, avoid = { S1 });
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Maple to assume your variable in your expression is positive or any other kind of similar assumption. Here is one way to do it.

```
eq:=abs(-5.58*L^(-1.88)) assuming L>0;
```

Then ask Maple to solve it by fsolve, it will automatically look for only positive solutions.

```
fsolve(eq = 3, L)
```

I received this result from Maple (2019).

```
1.391098714
```